# Why there is a space left between navbar and right edge of screen?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on web-development.
While coding with bootstrap framework, I got a problem.
In responsive test, there is some space left between navigation bar and the right edge of the screen. At that place there is a scroll bar. what should i do if i want my navigation bar behind that scroll bar 
[screen shot of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3xM2.png) 
can anyone tell me where i went wrong in my code.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.abhudaya {
  padding-top: 2.5%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222730;
}

.logo {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.contact-address-icon {
  width: 26px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.contact-address-headding {
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: white;
}

.contact-email-address {
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.navigation1 {
  background-color: #242933;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-tabs li a {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #242933;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #d5d5d5 !important;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.open .dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: #F9F1F0 !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>index abhudaya</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <div class="abhudaya container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><img src="images/call.png" alt="call" class="contact-address-icon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"></i><span class="contact-address-headding">lorem</span>
          <br><span class="contact-email-address">lorem</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><img src="images/location.png" alt="location" class="contact-address-icon"><span class="contact-address-headding">lorem</span><br><span class="contact-email-address">lorem</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation1 container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default container-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navigation-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BAND</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TOUR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a margin and padding to the toggle button `.navbar-toggle`

Add this class to your css to remove padding and margin

```
.navbar-toggle
 {
   padding-right: 0px!important;
   margin-right: 0px!important; 
 }
```

Full code

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.abhudaya {
  padding-top: 2.5%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222730;
}

.logo {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.contact-address-icon {
  width: 26px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.contact-address-headding {
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: white;
}

.contact-email-address {
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.navigation1 {
  background-color: #242933;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-tabs li a {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #242933;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #d5d5d5 !important;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.open .dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: #F9F1F0 !important;
  color: red !important;
}
.navbar-toggle
 {
   padding-right: 0px!important;
   margin-right: 0px!important; 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>index abhudaya</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <div class="abhudaya container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><img src="images/call.png" alt="call" class="contact-address-icon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"></i><span class="contact-address-headding">lorem</span>
          <br><span class="contact-email-address">lorem</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><img src="images/location.png" alt="location" class="contact-address-icon"><span class="contact-address-headding">lorem</span><br><span class="contact-email-address">lorem</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation1 container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default container-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navigation-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BAND</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TOUR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae nostrum magni tempora repellendus tenetur asperiores mollitia dignissimos libero hic, doloribus, exercitationem consectetur quas incidunt fugit perferendis fuga! Sint, eaque.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As u said i used it but it failed